# How to efficiently calculate hourly averages for infrequent data using KQL / ADX?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to calculate hourly averages for sensor data that is sent only for changes, in some cases as infrequently as every 6 hours (heartbeat interval).

The naïve approach would go something like this

```
T
| summarize avg(value) by bin(timestamp, 1h), systemID
```

The problem is that sometimes the bins are completely empty, which results in empty hours. The intended result would be that the empty hours would have the value of the last received value before that hour.

The other issue with this approach is if the data changes only few times per hour, it's not remotely accurate:

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, value:double, id:string) 
[ 
    datetime('2023-05-08T00:00:00Z'), 0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T00:01:00Z'), 1, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T00:02:00Z'), 2, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T03:00:00Z'), 3, 'test']
| summarize avg(value) by bin(timestamp, 1h), id
```

For example this query returns

```
timestamp   id  avg_value
2023-05-08T00:00:00Z    test    1
2023-05-08T03:00:00Z    test    3
```

While the closer correct value for 00:00 would be 2, as it is the last reported value and is "active" for the rest of the hour.

To try and fix these issues, I came up query that uses make-series and series_fill_forward:

```
let series_step = 10m;
let results_bin = 1h;
let series_length = 2d;
let lookback = 1d;
T
| make-series hint.shufflekey=systemID average=avg(value) default=double(null) on timestamp from ago(series_length+lookback) to now() step series_step by systemID
| extend fillforward = series_fill_forward(average)
| mv-expand timestamp, fillforward
| project systemID, fillforward = todouble(fillforward), timestamp = todatetime(timestamp)
| order by timestamp asc
| summarize hint.shufflekey=systemID average = avg(fillforward) by bin(timestamp, results_bin), systemID
```

This seems to work as I intended, however it uses over 5x the memory (peak per node) as the other approach and it starts to fail when I try to increase the series length:

> Partial query failure: Low memory condition (E_LOW_MEMORY_CONDITION). (message: 'bad allocation', details: '')"

My end goal is to have a 30 day materialized view for 1 hour aggregate data.

Is there something I could do to optimize this kind of approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mv-apply` on the series results:

```
let start=bin_at(now(-30d), 1h, datetime(1970-01-01 00:00:00));
let end=bin_at(now(), 1h, datetime(1970-01-01 00:00:00));
datatable(timestamp:datetime, value:double, systemID:string) 
[ 
    datetime('2023-05-06T00:00:00Z'), 0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-06T00:01:00Z'), 1.0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-06T00:02:00Z'), 2.0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-06T03:00:00Z'), 3, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-07T00:00:00Z'), 0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-07T00:01:00Z'), 1.0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-07T00:02:00Z'), 2.0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-07T03:00:00Z'), 3, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T00:00:00Z'), 0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T00:01:00Z'), 1.0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T00:02:00Z'), 2.0, 'test',
    datetime('2023-05-08T03:00:00Z'), 3, 'test'
]
| make-series hint.shufflekey=systemID val=max(value) default=double(null) on timestamp from start to end step 10m by systemID
| extend val = series_fill_forward(val)
| partition hint.strategy=native by systemID (
    mv-apply val to typeof(double), timestamp to typeof(datetime) on (summarize avg(val) by bin(timestamp, 1h))
  )
| render timechart
```

Peak Memory usage is 1.5MB.

Comment: you can create the materialized view with summarize, and then use make-series and series_fill_forward on top of the view, during query time, only to fill in the missing bins.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment yifats, it was:
" This is much better than what I did in terms of speed and memory usage! Now I have another issue, I can't use it in a materialized view query: "Expecting a pipe before the summarize operator". Is there any way around it? I removed the partition operator as those are not supported in materialized views. "

That would not fix my issue with inaccurate bins. I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/functions-library/time-weighted-avg-fl?tabs=query-defined which is even more accurate version of what im trying to do

Comment: @Ville: Do you really need it in a materialized view? MV's aren't free (computational wise) and the query seems cheap enough. If it gets called so frequently that it would really make a difference then one option is to maybe run the query once per 15min (or whatever refresh interval makes sense) and use the [Stored Query Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results) feature to retrieve them